# Typescript react setState on context return nothing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-context

I am using the context api to set the current logged in user.

UserContext.ts

```
const UserContext = createContext<IUser>({} as IUser);

export default UserContext;
```

The Layout component in which I set the user:

```
const Layout: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = ({ children }) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [user, setUser] = useState<IUser>({} as IUser);

  const getUser = async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get('me');
    setUser(data);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getUser();
  }, []);

  return (
    <main>
      <UserContext.Provider value={user}>
        {children}
      </UserContext.Provider>
    </main>
  )
```

So I fetch the user data from my api, I get the correct data.
Then I put the user as a value to my UserContext.Provider.

In another component I try to access the user data like this:

```
const Movies: NextPage<MovieProps> = props => {
  const userContext = useContext(UserContext);
  console.log("------------");
  console.log(userContext);
  console.log("------------");
}
```

The console just returns an empty object.

Comment: Can you create a working example, the above does look like it should work.  If you `console.log(data)` after you `axios.get`, do you get something?  IOW: Does your back end return an Object with a property called data?.

Comment: @Keith axios.get works it saves it properly to the state aswell, I just can't log the data in my other component, if I return the state afterwards it returns the proper data as a json object

Comment: useEffect is run after child component have re-rendered and hence the logs gives you the initial value as the data hasn't been available yet. However you must see the updated value when the data is available

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri hmm ok, but how do I accomplish this in what order / steps?

Comment: You can add a loading state and show a loader till the data is. available. Also make sure your API isn't failing